# CMake: Link different OpenCV libs to different executables of same project

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have a project which uses OpenCV and whose project files are generated via cmake. Now adding the opencv libs in CMake generally works like this:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core highgui gpu)
add_executable(SomeExecutable someSource.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SomeExecutable ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Which would link the libs core, highgui and gpu to this executable. Now if I have a project with multiple executables, is it possible to add different ones of the OpenCV libs to the different executables? (E.g. because I don't want the other application to load unnecessary libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not link your targets with all found packages. Instead of writing:

```
target_link_libraries(SomeExecutable ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

You might want to write:

```
target_link_libraries(SomeExecutable cxcore highgui)
```

For the names of OpenCV libraries check FindOpenCV.cmake file in your CMake path.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood what I meant. My problem is not, that I want to use two different instances of OpenCV which are at different locations. All I want is to be able to control, which modules are used for the different executables of the same project. E.g. I only want to use `core` and `improc` for the first but `core` and `gpu` for the second one. The OpenCV find script only defines the variable `OpenCV_LIBS` which contains all of the libs that was searched for. Of course I could try calling find_package two times with different module lists, but that doesn't appear very elegant.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Works great. However, the target names are slightly different for me (`opencv_core`, `opencv_highgui` instead of `cxcore`, `highgui` etc.). I use the cmake config script that comes with opencv.